# In ActionScript 3.0, how can you copy a video file from a remote server to a user's computer without using AIR or HTTP?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file-io, flash-media-server, remote-server

I've found how to do this with AIR and HTTP, but I need to, if possible, find a way to do this that circumvents both of these.  I've been looking for a way to do this and am continuing to do so, but I haven't met with success just yet.  Perhaps there's some way to stream from a file in the background, grab the data, and pack that in a new file or something (although I haven't found anything like that yet)?

Is there a way to copy videos like that without AIR or HTTP?  What might it be?  Thanks!

EDIT: Let me clarify:  There is a file called "x.avi" on some remote server that we only have partial access to.  It is not on the Flash server.  We cannot use HTTP.  We cannot use AIR.  We have to be able to use RTMP to NOT stream the file, but to actually save it onto a random person's computer over the Internet.  Adobe likes to keep Flash Player and stuff locked down like there's no tomorrow, so it's been very difficult to find a class or something to do this with.  I've found classes for streaming (which we're already doing), saving a file on the FMS's server, etc., but not for this.

Comment: If you want to avoid HTTP, what protocol do you want to use on the server?

Comment: @Panzercrisis, what is your protocol ???

Comment: We're using RTMP right now.  We're already streaming the video, but the client was wanting a way to download the files and save them onto their computers over the web without using HTTP.

Comment: RTMP is not HTTP this should be acceptable to the client. Clients are generally dumb it is your job to enlighten them on how the internet works.

Comment: But I'm not really in contact with them myself, and my superiors, though they may have already done that by now, were hoping to avoid issues with them.  But the problem is being able to use the RTMP protocol to save a video onto a random user's computer without using AIR.  So far I haven't found anything that works.  So far we're just able to stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileReference.download(), but I guess this is not what you intend.

Unfortunately you are not have disk access in flash, so even if you have the video bytearray I think it is not possible to save it.

Comment: I tried FileReference.download() earlier, but then I was told I couldn't use HTTP.  If there's a work-around so that you can use it without HTTP though, it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at the `SharedObject` class, there are file size limitations, but you can prompts users to increase their local shared object storage limit
[documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Can you use RTMP?](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#NetStream%28%29)

```
var my_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
my_nc.connect("rtmp://www.yourfmsserver.com/someappname");
var my_ns:NetStream = new NetStream(my_nc, NetStream.CONNECT_TO_FMS);
my_ns.play(videoURL);
var my_video:Video = new Video();
my_video.attachNetStream(my_ns);
addChild(my_video);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was needing to save the file on the user's computer.

Comment: OK? So write the RTMP stream to a file. I fail to see what the issue is.

Comment: The trouble I've had is finding a class/technique that can be used for that when you're not using Adobe AIR or HTTP, and when the computer you're downloading it to is a completely random user's computer.

Comment: Ok then the next question is why save it to the local clients machine at all. Are you trying to avoid multiple streaming of the same file to the client?

Comment: The client basically asked for it.  They asked to have it where all of their employees can do so from the web.

Comment: By now they may have been told it's not possible unless we're able to use HTTP or something though.